# NodeJS SSH Connection

Tags: node.js, ssh

I'm looking for a way to SSH to one of our remote servers programatically using NodeJS. However, whenever we SSH to the server, we need to enter a 1-Time Code as an extra security feature. I'm currently using [simple-ssh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-ssh). Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Can you connect to this server using the `ssh` command-line utility? Running `ssh -vvv` and connecting to the server will make ssh print debugging output as it runs. If you do that and [edit] your question to include the debugging output, someone should be able to tell you how to perform this extra authentication in node.js.

Comment: FWIW the most recent versions of `ssh2` now support custom authentication method order handling (via an `authHandler` callback), so you can now for example perform keyboard-interactive auth first and then password/publickey auth.

Comment: @mscdex do you have any usage example with `authHandler`? Can it be used with certificate authority?

Answer (score 0):

You can do so using `node-ssh`, below is a simple example that using Environment Variables to SSH to a hostname server (IP or DNS based) and run `redis-cli` command to ping. Also, we read the output through STDOUT and STDERR:

```
const node_ssh = require('node-ssh');
const ssh = new node_ssh();

require('dotenv').config();

ssh
  .connect({
    host: process.env.SSH_host,
    username: process.env.SSH_user,
    privateKey: process.env.SSH_privatekey,
    passphrase: process.env.SSH_passphrase
  })
  .then(() => {
    ssh.execCommand('redis-cli ping', { cwd: '/var/www' }).then((result) => {
      console.log('STDOUT: ' + result.stdout);
      console.log('STDERR: ' + result.stderr);
    });
  });
```

[Click here](https://grizzlybit.info/blog/how-to-ssh-using-nodejs) to get a detailed example.